# Why shouldn’t I use my 4G mobile connection for business Internet?

Tags: internet-connection

I’m paying Brighthouse $90/month for a 25/2 connection while my phone gets almost 100/30 and I can put it on a mobile hotspot and get comparable speeds.

I mean, it looks like I should be able to just cancel my business Internet and use my mobile hotspot. Am I missing a downside to this? It’s still cheaper even if I add another line to my account to use exclusively at the office. Is latency going to be a problem? Will downloads get interrupted or something?

Comment: Most mobile tarrifs are heavily restricted in terms of amount of data you can download per month. Most landlines in the UK now have unlimited data for £15 to £20 per month, while £40 will get you between 6 to 10 GB of data on a mobile on the major providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing a downside to this?

There are a few downsides to wireless data, but it’s your decision whether they impact your usage.

- **Outages When the Wind Blows Too Hard:** First, since it’s wireless data—and not wired—you are at the mercy of the same ups and downs as all of us when dealing with mobile data. Some days it can be good, some days it can be bad. I had some 4G outages myself during bad weather. The good side is since wireless outages affect more people than—let’s say—a tree trunk bringing down a phone company line, the company providing wireless service has more motivation (aka: people complaining) than a smaller group of people with a similar wired outage.
- **Speed is Not Guaranteed:** If your phone gets 100/30, are you 100% sure that is all of the time? Or a guaranteed peak? The reason being is most wireless data providers don’t ever guarantee per-user/per-connection speeds. So you would only see that 100/30 during off hours and maybe only see 50/10 during peak. In contrast, if you purchase a wired 25/2 connection, you are guaranteed that speed at all times.
- **Latency is Not Great:** In general, wireless connections are great for downloads—meaning any data coming to your connection—but are spotty when dealing with juggling uploads. Ping latency is pretty much guaranteed to be **worse** on a wireless data connection when compared to a wired connection.
- **Data Charges/Throttling:** Now this might depend on your plan and service level, but most data plans are capped. In the U.S. some providers—such as Clear 4G—provide unlimited data for a flat fee a month. But generally if you sign up for a wireless data plan, you have a cap and what happens when you reach that cap is up to the provider. You might end up paying through the nose in overage charges or your Internet speed crawls to a useless halt.
- **Using Your Own Phone Can Be a Pain:** The problem with using your own phone as an access point for your office network connection is… What happens when your phone dies? Or heck, what happens when you are not in the office? Does all connectivity go down? Can your business live with that? Perhaps you are thinking of getting a second device, but just something to keep in mind since many people tend to forget that where they are with their phone and where their computer is tends to be different places at different times of the day.

So overall, it all depends on your work habits and business needs. But when all is said and done, going 100% wireless runs the risk of forgoing stable service—via a wired connection—for the relatively cheaper speed of a wireless data connection. Not to mention if you “put all your eggs” in one basket what happens when the wireless data plan suffers an outage or slowdown? With a wired connection you at least have a backup to do some work or just do anything. If your wireless data connection goes out the day of a big meeting, how would you recover from that or does that even matter?

Comment: I think I have all of those downsides plus terrible service with Brighthouse, but I did look into it and you're right, all of the unlimited plans for our available mobile providers throttle for hotspots. Looks like I'm stuck for now.